# Is it possible to chain several Select clauses with gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I know I can chain several Where clauses using gorm, but can I do the same with several Select clauses ?

I've tried something like this with no luck:

```
query.Select("field1, field2").Select("field3").Find(&models)
```

The fact is that I need to chain different select clauses depending on certain conditions. How to achieve this?

Comment: Im not sure that’s possible. You can pass a slice of strings to select Select([]string{“field1”}) , you could build this array conditionally and then pass it in?

Answer (score 1):

Chaining multiple `Select()` calls won't work, as it will only apply the **last** one. So in your example, the query will look like:

```sql
SELECT "field3" FROM "model";
```

`Select()` also accepts a `[]string`, so instead, make a slice of strings representing the fields that you need to `SELECT`, and append to it other columns under certain conditions:

```golang
selects := []string{"field1", "field2"}

if condition {
    selects = append(selects, "field3")
}

query.Select(selects).Find(&models)
```